# Ubuntu not loading Ui on virtual box

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I tried modifying (increasing) the disk space of my Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop on windows 10 on Virtual box version 6.1 and the initial steps I followed where as follows

File => virtual media manager

After completing the above process i tried restarting the VM but it i receive the text show on the image below. Would really Appreciate the Assist in figuring out the issue . Thanks

[image: Here is the image]

This goes on for hours. How can I fix this?

Comment: Which "Ubuntu 18" did you install? Ubuntu Core 18? Ubuntu Server 18.04? Or Ubuntu Desktop 18.04? 

Comment: it's ubuntu 18.04 @matigo

Comment: it's ubuntu 18.04 Desktop. Prior it had been working and i tried increasing the disk space by going to file => virtual media manager . Then when i tried restarting it i get the above  as seen on the screenshot  @matigo

Comment: Ah, this is a rather important piece of data that should have been part of the question. There is no way someone would have guessed that you were modifying disks ...

Comment: update the question . Thanks @matigo

Comment: Does your VM contain the required specs for a Ubuntu 18.04 system (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements).   Also note VirtualBox can misbehave if VMs are given too few resources (Oracle state this is a end-user error & not a `virtualbox` bug)

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen for a few reasons when running Ubuntu Desktop in VirtualBox:

1. the VM's disk containing `/` is full (or non-existent)
2. PAE/NX is not enabled
3. insufficient CPU resources (not enough cores)
4. video driver issue as a result of 3D Acceleration

As you've said in a comment that things were working beforehand, I would lean towards the first possibility. Boot the VM with an installation `.iso` and use a Live Session to see if the disks are okay. If one is completely full, which would make sense given that you were trying to add space, it may be necessary to move or delete files beforehand.

If you are unable to move or delete files, then you will want to add another virtual disk to the VM, format it (in a Live Session), and move files to make space.